# Referencing Bootstrap CSS and custom CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reference my own CSS and Bootstrap CSS in my personal website. But I only can reference to Bootstrap's styles and my CSS background color is gone. Why does that happen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="bio.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width,initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">About me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox"></span>Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
    <body>
        <a href="bio.css">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h1><a href="bio.css"> Bio </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a href="#"><img src="propic.jpg" alt="Propic" width="354" height="354">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <p><a href="#"> paragraph 1 </p>
                <p><a href="#"> paragraph 2</p>
                <p><a href="#"> paragraph 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: css sequence is wrong. First add bootstrap.css and second add your own css bio.css.
Also check the path of your bio.css.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your own bio.css after bootstrap.css framework so that your css can overwrite bootstrap.css.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bio.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

1. Set `<link href="bio.css" rel="stylesheet">` after `<link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`
2. Check if the color is white

Comment: don't need to add important if specificity is set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your head css calls should be in the right order, bootstrap first, and your stylesheet last so it will override anything in bootstrap css:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bio.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Also make sure not to call a css file in a href tag inside the body as you have done, it's semantically incorrect, unless you want to show that stylesheet, but I don't think you ever would:

```html
<body><a href="bio.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put you own css sheet after bootstrap, otherwise the bootstrap will cover you own css since **"The last rule defined overrides any previous, conflicting rules"**. Your head css should be write in that order:

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bio.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

And here is a nice article about css specificity(priority), you can find more rules there: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Put you own css sheet after bootstrap, otherwise the bootstrap will override your own css and simply change your css name to **custom.css**.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width,initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="bootstrap-3.3.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```